# C++ Socket (TCP) doesn't accept external connections on Windows but on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sockets, tcp

i'm working on an simple network server example. It should accept TCP- and UDP-requests and answer with an asctime string. UDP is working whithout any issues. TCP makes some problems on windows. I work on linux for myself but have to make this little example running on windows. The university PCs are running windows. So for your information i tried crosscompiling and even compiling on the system itself.

The actual problem is on linux is everything working fine. The following code is my attempt to realise a non-blocking TCP-listener which responds with the asctime-string when it gets a request (user defined port not only 13):

```
void Server::tcpListen(int port)
{
    socklen_t size = sizeof(sockaddr);
    sockaddr_in remoteHost;

    mAddress.sin_port = htons(port);

    int r = bind(mTcpSocket, (sockaddr*) &mAddress, sizeof(sockaddr));

    if(r < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Couldn't bind port. (" << std::strerror(errno) << " " << errno << ")" << endl;
        #ifdef WIN32
                cerr << "WSA Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        #endif
        mTcpServerRunning = false;
        return;
    }

    cout << "TCP:\tListen on port " << port << '\n';

    r = listen(mTcpSocket, 5);

    if(r < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Couldn't listen. " << std::strerror(errno) << " " << endl;
        mTcpServerRunning = false;
        return;
    }

    time_t t;
    struct tm *timeinfo;
    std::string timeMsg;

    mTcpServerRunning = true;

    while(mTcpServerRunning)
    {
        int cSock = accept(mTcpSocket, (sockaddr*) &remoteHost, &size);
        if(cSock < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        char buf[5];

        r = recv(cSock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

        if(r > 0)
        {
            time(&t);
            timeinfo = localtime(&t);
            timeMsg = asctime(timeinfo);

            r = send(cSock, (char*) timeMsg.c_str(), timeMsg.length(), 0);

            if(r < 0)
            {
                cerr << "send error: " << errno << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            uint8_t ip[4];
            memcpy(ip, &remoteHost.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(ip));

            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Request-Type: TCP" << " / " << timeMsg.c_str() << endl;
            cout << "IP: "
                    << (int) ip[0]
                    << "." << (int) ip[1]
                    << "." << (int) ip[2]
                    << "." << (int) ip[3]
                    << " / Port (Client): " << remoteHost.sin_port << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;   
        }
    }
    close(mTcpSocket);
    #ifdef WIN32
        WSACleanup();
    #endif
    mTcpServerRunning = false;
}
```

To debug the connection i used wireshark which told me the connection attempt isn't unanswered. The initialisation with the three-way-handshake works (SYN -> SYN, ACK -> ACK). Even the request (empty string) is working. (PSH, ACK -> ACK) but the server doesn't respond with the time-string. I opened the ports and even disabled the firewall completely.

Is there anything wrong with the WSASocket usage? Blocking TCP-receiving doesn't work either. I have thought about the loop repeating before answering and then overwriting the `cSock` descriptor returned from accept.

**EDIT:** Initialization of the sockets:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "WSAStartup(): Couldn't initialize Winsock.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
#endif

mTcpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
mUdpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

#ifdef _WIN32
    unsigned long nonblocking = 1;

//            if(ioctlsocket(mTcpSocket,FIONBIO, &nonblocking))
//                    std::cout << "Couldn't set TCP-Socket to nonblocking mode! ("
//                                    << std::strerror(errno) << ")" << endl;

    if(ioctlsocket(mUdpSocket, FIONBIO, &nonblocking))
            std::cerr << "Couldn't set UDP-Socket to nonblocking mode! ("
                            << std::strerror(errno) << ")" << endl;
#else

    int tcpFlags = fcntl(mTcpSocket, F_GETFL, 0);
    int udpFlags = fcntl(mUdpSocket, F_GETFL, 0);

    if(fcntl(mTcpSocket, F_SETFL, tcpFlags | O_NONBLOCK))
        std::cout << "Couldn't set TCP-Socket to nonblocking mode! ("
                << std::strerror(errno) << ")" << endl;

    if(fcntl(mUdpSocket, F_SETFL, udpFlags | O_NONBLOCK))
        std::cerr << "Couldn't set UDP-Socket to nonblocking mode! ("
                << std::strerror(errno) << ")" << endl;
#endif
```

Comment: Firewall perhaps?

Comment: Do you call `WSAStartup`, do you properly initialize `sockaddr` structures?

Comment: You aren't checking the result of `recv()` for either zero or -1, and there is another place where an error is noticed but not printed or logged.

Comment: Unless the address part of `maddress` is set to INADDR_ANY, this code will only listen at one IP address. Unanswerable without this further information. And non-blocking mode is pointless without `select()` or `poll()` and friends.

Comment: @EdHeal I disabled any firewalls. 

@EJP I've  set and initialized with INADDR_ANY and set the "nonblocking behaviour" via `fcntl()` / `ioctlsocket()`. For now i removed only the windows (`ioctlsocket()`) and suddenly it works as expected. So my resume is that linux needs `fcntl()` but windows doesn't. The next resume is to use `select()` or `poll()` in the future. But i don't understand the reason behind the behaviour i experienced now. Any suggenstions?

Comment: @VTT Yes i'm initializing sockaddr with `mAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;` and `mAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);` and calling WSAStartup including checking the result.

Comment: So it looks like you are not initializing `mAddress` properly. You need to fill it with zeroes first to ensure that any fields that you didn't fill manually contain default values.

Comment: A memset before initializing would be the way to go..? Like `memset(&mAddress, 0, sizeof(sockaddr));`

Comment: If you are using newer standards it can be initialized at declaration with `mAddress{}`. If you go with `memset` then you need to pass `sizeof(mAddress)`.

Comment: `sizeof(sockaddr))` should be `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`, or better `sizeof(mAddress)`. And where is the code that initializes `mTcpSocket`? And don't use `errno` on Windows, only use `(WSA)GetLastError()`

Comment: What do you mean 'any suggestions'? I've made about five.

Comment: @VTT thanks, i'll take it into account.
@EJP I wanted to understand why it doesn't work when i set the socket to nonblocking with `ioctlsocket()` on Windows but on Linux it works as supposed with `fctnl()`. I've edited the question with the initialization. That's how it's now and it's working. But i don't understand why it's working nor why it wasn't working at all. Buy i want to.
@RemyLebeau thanks, i'll add this to it.